# Are muʿtazilah scholar considered as heretics according to sunni scholar?

Tags: sunni, mutazilites

Are muʿtazilah scholar considered as heretics according to sunni scholar?

If yes when why do sunni scholar considered Muʿtazilah heretic

Comment: I don't think they are heretic

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are considered a heretical sect with many deviant beliefs, however the scholars differed about doing takfīr upon them. Most scholars generally do not, unless they fall into clear kufr which is beyond any ta'wīl.